# Como hacer un evento para que despues de ciertos días se modifique el campo de una de mis tablas

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, events

Holaaa buen día, alguien me podria ayudar, quiero hacer un evento para que despues de ciertos días un campo de mi tabla se modifique, eh estado investigando pero no logro concretar mi idea, utilizo phpmyadmin ya que tengo un paquete de hosting y sobre ese trabaajo

Comment: y que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Tengo la idea de codigo del evento pero, no se como aterrizarlo o ingresarlo dentro de phpmyadmin

Comment: Revisa la respuesta dada en la pregunta referida arriba. En primer lugar, los eventos funcionan a partir de la versión 5.1.6 de MySQL, verifica que cumples con esa condición (puesde ejecutar `select version();` para verificar la versión). En segundo lugar, programa el evento, poniendo dentro tu consulta escrita de manera correcta (allí es un `DELETE` debes cambiarlo por un  `UPDATE` para tu caso). Luego guardas el evento y éste se ejecutará con la frecuencia que hayas indicado.